# How to use a select query in the where clause in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve everything from a table where the invoiceNo is distinct.So here is what I tried.

```
SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE 'invoiceNo' IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT(invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items`);
```

When I try this in php myadmin I get the following warning with no output.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2.

And when I run my php script from my android app it returns nothing.Is there a place where I can check my query like php code checker.

I am new to programming so any help and suggestion is welcome.Thank you :)

Comment: Column name in `quotes` is the problem use backtick instead

Comment: This will just select everything from the table again as you do not limit the number of results per distinct `invoiceNo`. (plus Saty is right about the wrong quotes around `invoiceNo`.)

Comment: And there is a randon backtick at the end of the inner query. VTC as typo.

Comment: You can also use `GROUP BY` `invoiceNo` instead of extra `IN` query

Comment: @Saty now the query works but as marcolz said I am getting everything from the table. so how do I limit the number of results per distinct invoiceNo.

Comment: @marcolz how do I limit the number of results per distinct invoiceNo.

Comment: @anup Use the `GROUP BY invoiceNo` as Saty mentioned 3 comments up.

Comment: @marcolz I tried this SELECT * FROM `selected_items` WHERE GROUP BY invoiceNo; but it is giving warning.

Comment: @anup: `SELECT * FROM selected_items GROUP BY invoiceNo;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Saty already mentioned in a comment: you probably mean:

```
SELECT * FROM selected_items GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```

Comment: Thank you so much marcolz :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE 'invoiceNo' IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT(invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items`);
```

To

```
 SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE invoiceNo IN (SELECT DISTINCT(invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) GROUP BY invoiceNo
```

Because invoiceNo is a column name, you should not be using the quotes on it, either leave it like it is or use backticks.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work for me.Now I am getting all the data like Select * from some table.

Comment: @anup So what is your expected results from the query..?done

Comment: @anup Please check my updated answer...that should work for you...done

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "`" symbol end of your code and remove single quotes in field name because values only need single quotes.

Like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE invoiceNo IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT(invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "`" symbol end of your code and

You try this one....

```
SELECT * FROM `selected_items` WHERE `invoiceNo` IN (SELECT DISTINCT(invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items);
```

Comment: Thanks vishu  I tried both your codes the both give everything from the table I want the invoiceNo to be distinct in the 2nd query.

Comment: It still returns everything from the table