# Laravel ULID Where=1 statement always return true

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9, navicat

I have table with Ulid as primary key, in example `SELECT * from ref_negara where id=1`, it always return all record, Unlike UUID. If i change to `SELECT * from ref_negara where id=2` it didnt return at all like it should be.

Does anyone know?

the query result's is not as expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a select query in the where clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199570/how-to-use-a-select-query-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: no, my primary key id, use ULID laravel, like 01gq40fqm7mhtajcn631p3e61c. But the result always return all record if i filter with 1, just like not filtered at all